# Client: How transactions are cleaned from transaction pool as they're included into blocks (where in client codebase?)

Tags: go-ethereum, clients

Hej, studying Ethereum client codebase, Geth and also a bit of the other ones like cpp-Ethereum and OpenEthereum. Can easily see where transactions are added to blocks (commitWork/fillTransactions/commitTransactions in Geth), but cannot see where they are cleaned up from the transaction pool. I assume it would be called or initialized from where validation of blocks occur, such as StateProcessor or in consensus engine, maybe it is done via events, I cannot find it. Anyone able to point me to where it is done?

**Edit:**

OK. It seems to be with the Reset method in SubPool interface. Called from the main loop in TxPool. Technically, transactions included in blocks are not removed specifically, rather, any transactions with a nonce lower than highest nonce used by an account are removed. Done in `demoteUnexecutables` method.